# Infinite loading if assign one permission inside another permission in rbac yii2

Tags: permissions, yii2, rbac

I have two permissions: "AdminAccess" and "settingaccess". They are assigned to "Admin" role.
In my code I check: Yii::$app->user->can("AdminAccess")...
If "settingaccess" permission is assigned to "Admin" role, it works fine and checking performs good. But if I remove this permission from Admin role and put it inside "AdminAccess" permisssion ("AdminAccess" permission remains assigned to "Admin" role) then when I refresh my page, it keeps loading infinitely. I even have to restart my server soft (OS Panel in my case). 
Is it a "rbac" bug? I wonder why permission put inside another permission is not working.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: A also have a rule assigned to "AdminAccess" permission in which I check Yii::$app->user->can('settingsaccess'). Is it possible that this checking might invoke infinite checking?

Comment: yes, it was because of that

Comment: It seems to me that checking "settingsaccess" invoke checking "AdminAccess" because the former is put inside the latter